# How do I convert a Float column in an OML DataFrame into an Integer column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I am using the oml4py python library, and have created an OML DataFrame containing a column of Floats that I would like to cast as a new column of Integers.

I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import oml
data = {"id" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "val" : [4.0, 3.0, 6.0, 7.0, 5.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
DF = oml.push(df)
DF["val"].astype(int)
```

but that errors out with

`AttributeError: 'Float' object has no attribute 'astype'`

Comment: Why not just convert the df column before you use oml.push?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

#
Import the OML4py 'oml' library and and pandas library

```
import oml 
import pandas as pd
```

#
Create a test DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "num":[4, 3, 6.3, 7.4, 5]})
```

# Create temporary OML proxy object DF

```
DF = oml.push(df)
```

# id is class oml.core.float.Float

```
type(DF['id'])
```

# Convert id to Integer type using the oml.Integer() function

```
DF2 = oml.Integer(DF["id"]).concat(DF["num"])
```

# id is now class oml.core.integer.Integer

```
type(DF2['id'])
```